# Call parent directive function from ngClick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Consider the following directive: ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YDRHwhFmVdja6g8C5PDc))

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            opt: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.foo = function() {
                console.log('bar');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And html:

```
<div my-directive>
    <a ng-click="foo()">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

Clicking the link does not trigger `foo()`, probably because of the isolated scope (because if I remove it - it works).
How can I make it work *with* an isolated scope?

EDIT:
The inner html is dynamic, so I can't use `template`

Thanks!

Comment: If your inner html is always the same, you should use a template that contains <a ng-click="foo()">Click Me</a>.

Right now, you are actually calling foo() on parent scope.

Comment: Unfortunately the inner html is not always the same. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS:

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                opt: '='
            },
            template: function (element, attrs) {
                return element.html();
            },
            controller: function () {
                var vm = this;
                vm.foo = function () {
                    alert('bar!');
                }
            },
            controllerAs: 'Ctrl'
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div my-directive>
    <a ng-click="Ctrl.foo()">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGegNV

Answer (score 2):

Well, the simplest way would be to just move the inner html into the `template` property of the directive:

```
        angular
        .module('myApp', [])
        .directive('myDirective', function() {
            return {
                scope: {
                    opt: '=',
                    foo: '&'
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.foo = function() {
                        console.log('bar');
                    }
                },
                template: '<a ng-click="foo()">Click Me</a>'
            }
        });
```

And html:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZbL2jVCdHuB4dP4y13fv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could wire-up the click event handler in the directive itself:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
              opt: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.on('click', function() {
                  console.log('bar');  
                })
            }
        }
    });
```